# New additional Point Rating for users

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, voting

Currently, the point rating (PR) is the main user success feedback. Have you ever thought about the new **additional** point rating (NPR) based on weights?

That would be like this:

```
A, B, C, D are users.
...
A has 25 points
B has 1000 points
...
C has 1 upvote from A.
D has 1 upvote from B.
=>
D should have greater NPR than C.
...
```

Also, another thing needs to be taken into account.

```
G is the user
G has 25 points   
...
If G voted 600 times his votes should play no important role for the NPR.
```

Note this is not a fraud. G only tried to get the Gold badge. This is because some people may create accounts on their mobile phones and use them for raffle voting. The NPR algorithm should diminish those and make them look like the little babies. Imagine Google PageRank algorithm. You are losing the substance if you link too much.

Another thing...

```
H, h1 are users
...
if H received 100 (hundred) votes and 25% of his votes are from user h1
```

User h1 should not contribute to the NPR score of H that much. This is not a fraud but should be called some second order fraud.

Note this may be the **additional** new point rating, so it will not remove or hurt the old one.

If *B* has 1000 pts, he showed possible a great effort to create his reputation. *B* also knows to value points and provides respectable feedback. The analogy with business success, if *B* has a great business, you trust him more over the *A*.

Real life: When you search for the now job position, you typically like better-rated companies over the lower rated. The same here.

There may be many other reasons why this may be smart.

This is just the initial proposal. Technically this can be done in superior quality I strongly believe because modern math theory may wing this idea. I am open if anyone needs more help from me.

This may be the challenge also, but we love challenges if they are smart. I haven't said this is smart. But if you think this is smart, don't care about computational complexity. Modern hardware can probably do that real time, else it can be done once daily or so.

And downvotes should also be in the formula. Not to forget that.

There will be certain coefficients that may change over time. As the coefficients are updated NPR will update. NPR may be something experimental at the very start.

The upvote from 25pts user vs. those having thousands of points should be different.

> Q. The problem is how do you act if you change any of the parameters. If a scheme is continuously tweaked, it loses credibility.

A. After the experimental phase, the NPR will not update considerable. Take Google PageRank for instance. If you like the NPR may be something hidden at first.

Comment: Why is an upvote from a user with 1000 rep more worth? At the moment votes are about the content and only about the content of a post. What issue does get solved with this weighted score? Additional to what?

Comment: there are many reason, I am afraid I cannot provide the answer good enough.

Comment: Start with one reason, because honestly I don't see any but I'm happy to be enlightened ...

Comment: Keep in mind that this will be the additional new point rating, so it will not hurt the old one. Keep in mind that usually if B has 1000 pts, he showed probable  great effort to create his reputation. B also knows to value points and provides respectable feedback. Analogy with business success, if B has great business, you trust him more over the A. When you search for the now job position @rene, you typically like better rated companies over the lower rated. The same here. Keep in mind this is a partial answer. I haven't tried to lighten anyone with this. I was just proposing ...............

Comment: [Edit] your question; don't leave important information in the comments.

Comment: How would this work over time then? Is the post I voted on in 2011 NPR'd against my rep from that moment? Or do all my votes get a higher rating due to my current rep?

Comment: This will dynamically update over time in my idea originally. Just like points. It is a computational task. This is not a problem for today's hardware. If still is a problem, it may be updated daily.

Comment: And in your example A and B are users and C and D are posts right?

Comment: Updated the post, all users. I haven't thought about the posts in there. But smart...

Comment: It feels this will become like the *people reached* stat but then on posts ...

Comment: @rene So in other words an immediate necessity.

Comment: If it is about users then I have to down vote this proposal. The sites are not about users, they are about content in posts and voting should be focused on that.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. You may propose something similar for posts.

Comment: But the voters are the people who have the trust while the poster is the person getting the reward... the entire thing is backward.

Comment: I'd rather you clarify your question so that it was possible to understand what you're asking for. Why is this better? Why do we need two different points systems at the same time? How does this add value?

Comment: @Catija, the more is sometimes better, it is better to have two eyes open than only one.

Comment: @Catija, this is similar like Google PR.

Comment: Only if downvotes get the same process.  And for ten times the weight.

Comment: @fbueckert, sure why not. Adding that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Too much complication for too little (really, no) gain.

Why should a person with more reputation have a weightier vote? There's plenty of people with a ton of reputation who wouldn't recognize a good (or bad) post if it walked up to them and handed over its business card.

Some people hand out votes like they're candy. Others hoard them, saving them for truly "worthy" posts. Shouldn't their votes be weighted differently?

Should someone who has been on the site a long time have weightier votes than the person who joined yesterday?

I don't see that this proposal solves anything other than adding more gravy for the data-hungry.

Comment: more information typically won't hurt, right? I prefer the color TV over the black and white one.

Comment: It can hurt, actually. What you've proposed would require significantly more processing power. Why do we need that?

Comment: Experts need to provide the feedback if this should happen on daily basis. My guess this will be easy even for real time. Upvote may trigger ... Hey, don't you like challenges?

Answer (score 8):

This is a bad idea. It's over-complicated and unnecessary. We already give people with reputation more voting power by not counting the votes of users with less than 15 reputation at all and by blocking users with less than 125 reputation from downvoting.

Additionally, you're rewarding the wrong person. Why does a user with any amount of reputation deserve a bigger reward just because a high-rep user decides to vote on their question or answer? What makes their content worth more or less depending on who's voting? That makes no sense. What it does is force high-rep users to be more considerate about rewarding their answers because (particularly with users who have very low rep), they could earn tons of privileges with just a couple of these votes from higher-rep users.

Now you have users who haven't done anything with lots of privileges and no site experience to know how to use them appropriately.... which means that we now have to possibly re-balance the privilege ladder. With a fixed vote value, it's less likely that a couple of votes will do any harm.

There's another thing you're missing.

Voting is anonymous. When every vote is worth the same amount, you have no way of knowing who cast that vote. If a high reputation user's votes are worth more, all of a sudden you can start guessing who placed that vote. On small sites, that could be just one or two people! On Arts & Crafts, there are only 13 users with over 1000 reputation.

High reputation users already have a mechanism to give a bonus to users who write excellent answers - the bounty system. If someone really feels strongly about an answer, they can give some of their reputation to that answer by offering a bounty on the question.

Comment: The question is not proposing a change to the rep earned from voting, so almost none of this answer applies to the question.

Comment: @Servy The question says nothing of the sort.

Comment: Right it doesn't specifically say that it's not, but it says that it's proposing a new metric, and mentions nothing about changing how reputation is awarded.  It does specifically call out that it's a new system that would not change or replace existing systems.  It doesn't call out reputation specifically, but the intent is rather clear.

Comment: @Servy The intent is utterly muddy. If it's not replacing the current system, why do we need **two** "point" systems? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Feel free to ask the OP that.  If you want to criticize the proposal because it's unnecessary, more power to you, just don't criticize it for the effects that it would have on systems it's not proposing any changes to.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like the idea.

1. Voting should really represent the quality of *that particular question or answer*. Anything else - such as the current reputation of the poster - ought not to be a consideration.
2. You'd have to recalculate the reputation of every user on the site. (This has been done before when the question upvote was changed from +10 to +5, but it's not something that ought to be done regularly).
3. How would the non-linearity be calibrated? How much more reputation would D earn than C? If the formula was ever changed, then reputation ought to be recalculated, again!
4. It could even introduce positive feedback loops into the system. Could people's reputation go to infinity?
5. Established users already earn more reputation than new users, all other things being equal: even I get a daily trickle of upvotes on old answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It is about being fair. G is the user, G has 25 points   
...
If G voted 600 times his votes should play no important role for the NPR.

Comment: Why do you have problems on `recalculate` thing? This is not humans will do.

Comment: 3. There will be certain coefficients that may change over time. As the coefficients are updated NPR will update. NPR may be something experimental at the very start.

Comment: 4. & 5. The math can deal with these so everything can be fair. The upvote from 25pts user vs. those having thousands of points should be a fraction difference.

Comment: The problem is how do you act if you change any of the parameters. If a scheme is continuously tweaked, it loses credibility.

Comment: After the experimental phase, the NPR will not update considerable. Take Google PageRank for instance. If you like the NPR may be something hidden at first.